# Adding outlet in middle of run

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I want to add an outlet in the middle of a run in my kitchen.  The start of the run has a GFCI outlet.  The outlet I want to extend off of is a regular 15amp with both line and load connections used (2 hot, 2 neutral, pigtailed ground).  The outlets all run off a 20amp breaker.

Assuming there is room to add another 12/2 line into the box how should I connect it to the existing outlet without affecting everything downstream?

Thanks!

[image: outlet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cut a hole for the new box
2. Run a new 12/2 cable from the old box to the new box location
3. Install the new box (note that you will need proper clamp, usually integral on a plastic box, separate and installed into a knockout on a metal box, in each box)
4. Disconnect the old white wires from the receptacle and connect them to the new white wire and a short white wire (pigtail) with a wire nut.
5. Connect the other end of the short white wire to one of the neutral screws on the receptacle.
6. Repeat 4 & 5 for the black wires.
7. Repeat 4 & 5 for the ground wires.
8. In the new box, connect black and white to hot & neutral screws on the receptacle.
9. If you use a metal box, connect the ground wire to a ground screw in the box. If you use a plastic box, connect the ground wire to the ground screw on the receptacle.
10. Since you *of course* used a better quality "self grounding" receptacle, if you used a metal box then the receptacle does not need a ground wire.

Comment: If you used a "self-grounding" receptacle then it probably has screw-and-clamp also, which allows 2 wires *under* each screw.  That allows 4 wires per side and removes the need for the pigtail.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That is often the case. However, I think that manipulating all the wires may actually be a little easier with pigtails, provided you can deal with wire nuts.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!